# angular 2 npm link Error in error encountered resolving symbol values statically. calling function 'makeDecorator'

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, angular-cli

I get an error when running my application if I use "npm link" to consume another package that I developed.

the error is:

Error in error encountered resolving symbol values statically. calling function 'makeDecorator'

Answer (score 1):

the solution is to add the following to the tsconfig.app.json file on the projects you use:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
        "@angular/*": ["../node_modules/@angular/*"],
        "@ngrx/*": ["../node_modules/@ngrx/*"],
        "rxjs/*": ["../node_modules/rxjs/*"]
        }
}
```